# DecisionTreeClassifier how to find next value

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

How to find next value after building a decision tree from the training set?
I need to know probability for next value of the A field in my example, when I put B and C values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 3)),
                    columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

>>>
    a   b   c
0   2   8   8
1   4   2   9
2   1   0   7
3   5   1   7
4   6   0   2

X = df[ ['b','c'] ]
Y = df[ ['a'] ]

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=241)
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

How to find out probability of the next value for field A if B=8, C=8 ?

Comment: If you want to predict a number, you should use DecisionTreeRegressor instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply use `clf.predict_proba()`. For example:

```
clf.predict_proba([[8,8]])
```

will return you a vector of float that represents the probability of the data being each of the unique value in column "a".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I do this function I see: "array([[1., 0., 0.]])"  But I thought it should be number and percent of probability like: Example: Next value will be 2 with probably 95%   ??(from DOC, predict_proba should return only 2 params:  array of shape = [n_samples, n_classes])

Comment: @Miraslav That means the probability of the input having the first label is 100%, it's probably just an extreme case since the example you are using is a very simple one.

Comment: I see now, Thanks! but is it possible to see labels too for result?

Comment: @Miraslav You can use `clf.predict([[8,8]])` to get the label with the largest probability. You can also use `clf.classes_` to get the class labels in the same order as the output from `clf.predict()`.